# How to get the current date format of Android emulator

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

I want to get the current **Date** Format of **Android** emulator. Can anyone help me?

Not like this

```
SimpleDateFormat FormattedDATE = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy");      
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not like this" ?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance()

Answer (score 2):

There are various options:

```
DateFormat defaultFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
DateFormat longFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
DateFormat mediumFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
// etc
```

And likewise for `getDateTimeInstance`.

Basically look at the static methods of [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) that return instances of `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

[`DateTimeFormatter#ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) provides a formatter that uses the locale-specific date format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        DateTimeFormatter shortDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                                                .localizedBy(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(shortDateFormatter.format(today));

        DateTimeFormatter mediumDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                                                .localizedBy(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(mediumDateFormatter.format(today));

        DateTimeFormatter longDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
                                                .localizedBy(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(longDateFormatter.format(today));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7/13/21
Jul 13, 2021
July 13, 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/JVLtqa)

Change the `ZoneId` and the `Locale` as applicable.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>